# To convert an absolute path to a relative path in php

Tags: php, relative-path

I would like to convert an absolute path into a relative path.

This is what the current absolute code looks like

```
$sitefolder  = "/wmt/";
$adminfolder = "/wmt/admin/";

$site_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."$sitefolder";

// $site_path ="//winam/refiller/";

$admin_path = $site_path . "$adminfolder";

$site_url    = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."$sitefolder";
$admin_url   = $site_url . "$adminfolder";

$site_images = $site_url."images/";
```

so for example, the code above would give you a site url of

```
www.temiremi.com/wmt
```

and accessing a file in that would give

```
www.temiremi.com/wmt/folder1.php
```

What I want to do is this I want to mask the `temiremi.com/wmt` and replace it with dolapo.com, so it would say `www.dolapo.com/folder1.php`

Is it possible to do that with relative path.

I'm a beginner coder. I paid someone to do something for me, but I want to get into doing it myself now.

Comment: You cant mask the domain, certainly not with php. If you own both domains, host your site in the other one, or point the other domain to the current server. This is NOT php.

Comment: are you just trying to change some values in a particular page?  if you mean to do this across-the-board, I'm starting to think I misunderstood and my answer isn't helpful, but ill leave it just in case.  The other issue is "relative" to what?  if you have temiremi.com/wmt/dir1/file.php  how is it supposed to be known whether you want to draw the line after 'wmt' or after 'dir1'?

Comment: I wish the question truly was how to convert an absolute path to a relative path, in general,instead of that specific problem description. The general question is much more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your question, although it seems very specific, is missing some crucial details.

If the script you posted is always being executed, and you always want it to go to `delapo.com` instead of `temiremi.com`, then all you would have to do is replace

```
$site_url    = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."$sitefolder";
```

with

```
$site_url    = "http://www.delapo.com/$sitefolder";
```

The `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` variable will return the domain for whatever site was requested. Therefore, if the user goes to `www.temiremi.com/myscript.php` (assuming that the script you posted is saved in a file called `myscript.php`) then `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` just returns `www.temiremi.com`.

On the other hand, you may not always be redirecting to the same domain or you may want the script to be able to adapt easily to go to different domains without having to dig through layers of code in the future. If this is the case, then you will need a way to figuring out what domain you wish to link to.

If you have a website hosted on `temiremi.com` but you want it to look like you are accessing from `delapo.com`, this is not an issue that can be resolved by PHP. You would have to have `delapo.com` redirect to `temiremi.com` or simply host on `delapo.com` in the first place.

If the situation is the other way around and you want a website hosted on `delapo.com` but you want users to access `temiremi.com`, then simply re-writing links isn't a sophisticated enough answer. This strategy would redirect the user to the other domain when they clicked the link. Instead you would need to have a proxy set up to forward the information. Proxy scripts vary in complexity, but the simplest one would be something like:

```
<?php
    $site = file_get_contents("http://www.delapo.com/$sitefolder");
    echo $site;
?>
```

So you see, we really need a little more information on **why** you need this script and its intended purpose in order to assist you.

Comment: SeFunmni: I'm a little confused. So right now you have a website hosted on kroesbergens.com, which can be accessed via temiremi.com (ie- both domains point to the same host). Also, you have dolapo.com redirecting to temiremi.com. My question is, where and why are you generating this absolute path? Do you have an `<a>` link which is pointing to it? Or are you trying to display the content of the other site without changing what the user sees in their URL bar? (By the way- this is not recommended for SEO reasons)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier to do in the HTTP server configuration. For example, using [Apache's VHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: I'll try this option too. I get my friend to set this up. I'll let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're going for bc this doesnt look like absolute path to relative path, but rather one absolute path to another.

Are you always trying to simply change "www.temiremi.com/wmt/" to "delapo.com"?  If thats the case, you just want simple string replacement rather than $_SERVER variables or path functions.

```
$alteredPath = str_replace("www.temiremi.com/wmt/", "delapo.com", $oldPath);
OR
$alteredParth "www.delapo.com/" . basename($oldPath)
```

If i misunderstand please explain, I don't know if you need this to be more robust/generic, and you kind of threw me for a loop with "dolapo.com" (when i first thought your title, i originally thought of comparing path to a value from $_SERVER and removing common parts,)

And as mentioned, if you are just trying to make the URL displayed the the user (in the address bar or links) look different PHP can't do this.

Comment: Yes, the string replacement I think is the best option. But would that show up in the address bar?

Like I want to  replace the temiremi.com/wmt with delapo.com only. That's all I want to do. And make sure it shows in the address bar (so that it becomes bookmarkable, i.e., it is callable).

Comment: if the page is really at delapo.com use header() to redirect there.  if it isnt, then no you can't "trick" the address bar like that with PHP